# Laying out a map using CSS

Tags: css

I have the following map: 
[image]

and I have created the matrixes that needs to populate this map (these are all tables)

[image]

My question is, how should I go about arranging these matrixes so that it will appear to look like the map?

I don't want to fixate on absolute positioning because I might change the width and height of the rows in the matrixes that I have created. Does anyone out there have a solution that is "flexible" enough to handle changes similar to what I have described?

Answer (score 0):

## HTML Structure

I think you should organize into two separate structures, and then organize each of those individual tables.

**Structure 1:**
A separate div, with a table inside.

**Structure 2**
A second div, the width of your page, containing five inline divs (acting as columns). Within each of those divs organize each matrixes in order you would like (organized in a one column wide x n number of rows per div)

*Code Code Code*

```
<div id="top"> 
    <table id="table_top">With rows/columns declared</table>
</div>

<div id="bottom">
    <div class="house"><table id="house1_table1></table>, etc</div>
    <div class="house"></div>
    <div class="house"></div>
    <div class="house"></div>
    <div class="house"></div>
```

*CSS CSS CSS*

```
#top {
  width: desired width;
  margin 0 auto; //to center block
}

#table_top {
  width: 100%; \\flexible width so you can grow each row without worrying about messing up structure. 
  height: desired height; \\not 100% to maintain structure more easily. 
 }
```

\add css to style upper rows and columns with desired width.

```
#bottom {
   width: 100%; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
   height: desired height; 
}

.house {
   width: 20%; \\gives each row the same width. 
   height: same as desired height for #bottom \\Make sure this heigh will accommodate all five columns in house1 row
   float: left; 
   display: inline; 


.house table {
   width: 90%; \\gives padding for aesthetic purposes without too much work. 
   margin: 0 auto; \\to center.
   height: number of tables/desired height - whatever padding is for aesthetics; 
   padding: 20px;
```

The main focus here is using a flexible model (i.e. tables within divs within divs) that allows you to change certain internal elements (i.e. the heigh of one row within the house 3, 3rd column) and not having to worry about the overall structure.